# Close Terminal window from within shell script (Unix)?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, command

Is there a way to close a Terminal window from within a shell script?  I have a .command file that should just get out of the way once it's done.

Comment: Then why open one in the first place?

Comment: Doesn't `exit -f` work for you? You might want to use `nohup` if you don't want your commands that are running to quit abruptly.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I run a script by double-clicking a .command file, the functionality is complete, end of operation.  i don't need the Terminal window hanging around.  What's confusing about this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Using `exit 0` will cleanly terminate the script.

Whether Terminal window stays open is user-configurable. The default is to always stay open. To change this:

```
Terminal.app > Preferences > Profiles > Shell
    - "When the shell exists:"
        > Close if the shell exited cleanly
    - "Ask before closing:"
        (•) Never
        -- OR --
        (•) Only if there are....
```

When "Close if shell exited cleanly" is used, the script will close the window if the exit result is 0, which is the default if nothing went wrong.

Comment: I do have "lose if shell exited cleanly" set, however in a certain script I want the terminal to stay open until user closes it... anyway around that?

Comment: Not directly (because `.command` adds `;exit` to the shell), but you call an AppleScript that doesn't close, e.g.: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e activate -e 'do script "run.my.jobs"' -e 'end tell'` -- that window will always stay open

Comment: Very cool. Thanks @SimonUrbanek. Getting my feet wet in the Appleverse and this tip is helping me automate some chores.

Comment: Works, but note that in Yosemite this preference is under Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles, then click on Shell tab.

Answer (score 29):

Since you don't want to delete all Terminal windows, first change the name of your window from "Terminal" to something else:

> echo -n -e "\033]0;My Window Name\007"

Then at the end of the script, use:

> osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose name contains "My Window Name")' &

Comment: Still asks for confirmation to close it unless you change Terminal pref.

Comment: @damasio If you change the end from `&` to `& exit` at the end there will be no confirmation dialog

Comment: @KevinM is it possible to close a specific tab rather than a whole window?

Answer (score 18):

You can use `apple script` to **quit** the `terminal app`. Add the following to your script -

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'
```

This will give you a popup confirming to close the app. You can disable this in Terminal preferences.

Alternatively, you can also use `killall` command to quit the app. The following would work just as well.

```
killall Terminal
```

#### Note:

Just as a side note, you can freely add the above commands to your script and it would work as you want. However, there are few caveats. **First** being you will limit the ability of your script to work on different boxes. **Secondly**, it would be safer to use `nohup` so that any commands that are currently running won't quit due to quitting of the `Terminal app`.

Comment: +1 I don't have a Mac so I'm going to assume this is the correct answer.

Comment: @SiegeX LOL .. I knew we could run `apple scripts` from terminal. Didn't really knew it was the `osascript` command. However, there is another cool command called `killall` which kinda does the same. Thank you for your trust and upvote. Appreciate it. :-)

Comment: ... wow - this is really radical - killing all open scripts is certainly not what I'd recommend. Note that the behavior is user-configurable so if you change your setting in *Settings* -> *Shell* -> *When the shell exists* to a more sane "Close if shell existed cleanly" then you simply need `exit 0` (or nothing) really.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek didn't realize Terminal had that config option.  That works perfectly.  Your comment is really a separate answer on its own -- I went ahead and wrote it up as an answer below.  Feel free to copy and paste it under your name if you want.  Thanks!

Comment: killall Terminal will kill all the terminal windows. Not at all user friendly option.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

{your script here}

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose name contains ".command")' &
exit
```

This will work for closing just your windows opened with a .command file but leave things already running in other terminal windows.  I know that I almost always have either sass or grunt watch something so I don't want to quit terminal totally.

Comment: Variation for when you'd also like Terminal to quit, but only if there's no more open windows. `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'close (every window whose name contains ".command")' -e 'if number of windows = 0 then quit' -e 'end tell' & exit;`. Multiple `-e`s add line breaks in the script; `"\n"` has issues for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
closeWindow() {
    /usr/bin/osascript << _OSACLOSE_
    tell application "Terminal"
        close (every window whose name contains "YourScriptName")
    end tell
    delay 0.3
    tell application "System Events" to click UI element "Close" of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Terminal"
_OSACLOSE_
}
```

This will close the Terminal window for your script and keep any other Terminal windows open as long as their window titles don't match. For it to work Terminal will have to be added to the list of applications permitted to use the Accessibility framework. You can also cycle through Terminal windows with a repeat command and close every window x that contains a UI element "Close" on sheet 1.

Comment: Where do I put this script?

Comment: Paste it inside your Bash script and call the **closeWindow** function when your script is completed. The function must be pasted into the script before it is called.

Comment: Had to activate Terminal as Accessibility for this. Feels a little like a security vulnerability... But works fine now thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I find the best solution for this is to use Automator to create a true OSX application which will work the same way regardless of how your system is configured.  You can have the Automator run your shell script, or you can embed the shell script itself in Automator.

Here is how you do it:

1. Run Automator (in Applications).
2. Choose "New Document" and when it
   asks "Choose a type for your document" choose "Application"
3. In the
   left panel, select "Utilities" then "Run Shell Script".
4. Type in your
   script commands in the workflow item in the right panel.  You can either call another
   shell script, or just put your commands in their directly.
5. Save the
   Application, which will be a full-fledged Mac App.  You can even
   cut-and-paste icons from other apps to give your script some
   personality.

Comment: Upvoted. Very useful and swift solution in my case (mac user).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash -x

{your script here}

. exit 0
kill -9 $PPID
```

you can also create a shortcut for your script:

```
cp yourscript.sh ~/bin/yourshortcutnamewhateveryouwant
```

then type

```
yourshortcutnamewhateveryouwant
```

will run whatever is writen into script at any directory.