# OSX Terminal close current tab from command line without prompt?

Tags: macos, tabs, terminal

Looking for a way to close the current tab via the command line, I hashed this out, but end up getting a prompt for *Do you really want to close* which I would like to avoid. Here's my code,

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "w" using command down'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close Terminal window from within shell script (Unix)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798641/close-terminal-window-from-within-shell-script-unix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why didn't use the:

```
Terminal.app -> Preferences -> Settings -> Shell
```

and for the items:

```
"When the shell exists:" Close if the shell exited cleanly
"Prompt before closing:" Only if there are...." (or Never)
```

Comment: Cheers, good answer I hadn't thought of that. +1 and accepted.

Comment: Not sure when this changed, but in 10.14 (Mojave) they're under `Preferences` -> `Profiles` -> `Shell`