# How to avoid a zombie window when running MacOS shel/Applescript script

Tags: macos, applescript

I routinely open a lot of Terminal windows each with an **ssh** session.  To streamline the process I have a series of shell scripts that look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<EOS
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "set_background_color salmon; ssh alan@demo.znyx.com"
end tell
EOS
```

This works.  I can either execute the script from a shell prompt or click it in the Finder window.   (To do this the file name suffix is **.command** instead of **.sh**)

The problem is that when I execute it from Finder, I end up with a dead window ("Process Completed") behind the window I intended to open.  Is there any way to get rid of it or not have it open in the first place?

UPDATE:

The solution in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565944) results in dialog boxes appearing that provide confirm/review/cancel options.   This is undesirable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mac ".command" file to automatically quit after running a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565944/how-do-i-get-a-mac-command-file-to-automatically-quit-after-running-a-shell-s)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara The solution in that other question doesn't work for me.  Every variation I try causes a dialog box to pop up to confirm closing this or other window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double-click a .command file, the file is passed to Terminal and Terminal creates a window and executes the commands within it. The commands in your .command file use AppleScript to tell Terminal to run a command in yet another window.

Why not remove the middle man and just put the ultimate commands you want to run — `set_background_color salmon; ssh alan@demo.znyx.com` — in the .command file? Drop that stuff with running an AppleScript. In other words, the contents of your .command file should just be:

```
set_background_color salmon
ssh alan@demo.znyx.com
```

Alternatively, you could take the AppleScript from your .command file (the part between `<<EOS` and `EOS`), put it into Script Editor.app, and save it as an applet.

Comment: Your answer works well enough (simpler is better!) that it is what I will use for now.  The reason I was trying to use Applescript is that I wanted to ultimately open windows programmatically -- one click to open a full set of any number similar to the "Open Window Group" menu option except with the connections already made.  That can wait for later though.